# TextArea not entering text

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 pages that have the same code for a textarea and on any other browser both pages work fine but on Windows 10 IE11 each page works individually when I load 1 then close the browser and load the next one but if i have the 1 page fill that in and submit then move onto the next page i click on the textarea and the placeholder text disappears but then cant type any text in.

```
<textarea id="UserTextInput" onClick="UserTextInputClick()"></textarea>
```

The read only is set to false on loads

```
$('#UserTextInput').prop('readonly', false);
```

Any ideas why this would be happening as the pages are working fine on there own and in other browsers?

Comment: Check that your code has compatibility with IE11?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Perhaps post the actual markup of each of the two pages instead - for example I see not placeholder related things here, be complete. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve